# Where to catch Post event?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, login

I use the following JavaScript to open new window in which Joomla login page displayed:

```
window.open('https://URL', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

The new window opens is as follows:

[image]

I need to populate the username in its field automatically. I found postMessage() method very suitable to do cross-domain communications (e.g., this [example](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage)) . So I amended my JavaScript like this:

```
var loginWindow = window.open('https://URL', '_blank', 'location=yes');
loginWindow.postMessage('username', 'foobar');
```

On the receiving side, (Joomla), I need to add this code in order to catch the post message:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  var message = event.data;
  $('input.login').val(message);
});
```

**My question is, where can I add this code?**
I'm not familiar with Joomla structure, and I did not see any JavaScript in the files like login form (components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php). So where can I add this JavaScript code. If I cannot, what alternatives do I have?

**Update**
Based on @Rene Korss advice, I added my code at the end of the following file `/templates/theme718/html/com_users/login/default_login.php`
I mention part of the previous code in the file to show its nature. My code starts from `<?php`

```
<script>
......
if(jQuery( window ).height()<620){
    jQuery('#copy-rightfp').addClass("copy-rightfps");
} else {
    jQuery('#copy-rightfp').removeClass("copy-rightfps");
}

function alertforget(){

    var div = '<div class="green"><p><?php echo JText::_('COM_FORGET_OOPS') ?></p></div><div class="font12"><p><?php echo JText::_('COM_FORGET_PLEASE_CALL') ?></p></div>';

    jQuery('#msgcontainer .note').html('');
    jQuery('#msgcontainer .note').append(div);

    jQuery('#msgcontainer').bPopup({
            modalClose: false,
            opacity: 0,
            positionStyle: 'fixed'
    });
}


<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();

$document->addScriptDeclaration("
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
      var message = event.data;
      $('input#username').val(message);
    });
");
?>

</script>
```

I find that the item I want to populate the message into called `username`, from below:

[image]

However, when the window opens, nothing occurs. No errors show in the console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would override Joomla! login view.

Copy contents of

`components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php`

and create new .php file in

`YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME/html/com_users/login/default_login.php`

and paste copied contents there.

> See Joomla! docs for [How to override the output from the Joomla! core](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core).

And then add javascript file or inline javascript to start of overrided file.

**Inline JS** (it adds code between `<head></head>` tags)

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration("
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
      var message = event.data;
      $('input.login').val(message);
    });
");
?>
```

OR

**External JS**

```
<?php
    $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->addScript('/wherever/your/js/file.js');
?>
```

You could add this JS file to your template folder or wherever your prefer. And add your code to JS file.

> See Joomla! docs for [Adding JavaScript](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript).

**EDIT:**

You are using `postMessage()` method improperly. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) you have to specify `targetOrigin`, which is second argument.

> If at the time the event is scheduled to be dispatched the scheme, hostname, or port of otherWindow's document does not match that provided in targetOrigin, the event will not be dispatched; only if all three match will the event be dispatched.

Currently it is `foobar`. So there is no match, and event wont be dispatched. 
Edit your code to this (replace `origin`).

```
loginWindow.postMessage('username_value_here', 'http://example.com');
```

**EDIT 2**

Since code was sending `postMessage` right after opening popup, it sent it too early. Destination wasn't loaded yet.

So we ended up with this code:

**Destination side**

```
/**
 * Ask for username from opener
 */

window.onload = function(){ 
    window.opener.postMessage('giveMeUsername', '*'); 
};

/**
 * Event to catch opener messages
 */

window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    // Allow only wanted domain
    if(event.origin !== 'http://example.com') return;
    var message = event.data;
    jQuery('input#username').val(message);
}, false);
```

**Opener side**

```
/**
 * Send username to popup, if it asks
 */
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    var message = event.data;

    // If popup asks for username
    if(message == 'giveMeUsername'){
        loginWindow.postMessage('username_value', '*');
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Where can I find the new directory to create new .php file? According to the reference, `beez` should be inside `templates` directory. I found directory `beez5` and `beez_20`, and html directory under them. But under html directory I did not find `com_users`, only found `com_contacts`

Comment: If it dosen't exist, you have to create this folder yourself. And this should be under your current template. In administrator go to `Extensions > Template Manager` and see what template is currently active for site location. Then you would create new file under that template folder.

Comment: I found from the administrator one template called `theme 718` has the sign assigned ticked which means it is the active one, isn't ? Now under the directory `templates/theme 718/html/com_users/login/` I found there is already a file called `default_login.php` with totally different contents.

Comment: Ok. Thats correct. Then just add the inline or external JS.

Comment: I added the code, it opens the window but no message is populated in `username` field input field. I'm not sure how to debug it to know if the code being run or not.

Comment: Check your console for errors. If you use jQuery, check if it gets loaded.

Comment: jQuery is loaded, but nothing happens, I updated my question with the last attempt

Comment: Your selector is wrong. Change `$('username').val(message);` to `$('input#username').val(message);`.

Comment: I did, same result. Nothing is populated. But I can confirm it is being executed as when I put some invalid JS, the window returns error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22464/discussion-between-rene-korss-and-hawk).